# Trying to store CMTime as Transformable property on Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, cmtime

I have used transformable properties of Core Data before but not with `C` objects like `CMTime`.

I need to store a `CMTime` on Core Data using transformable.

On the Model object I have declared this as transformable.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) id tempo;
```

I understand that `CMTime` is a `C` object and I need to convert this to a NSDictionary and serialize it, so I can store on Core Data.

On the `NSManagedObject` class, I have this...

```
+(Class)transformedValueClass
{
  return [NSData class];
}

+(BOOL) allowsReverseTransformation
{
  return YES;
}

-(id)transformedValue:(id) value
{
  CFDictionaryRef dictTime = CMTimeCopyAsDictionary(?????, kCFAllocatorDefault);
  NSDictionary *dictionaryObject = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:(__bridge NSDictionary * _Nonnull)(dictTime)];
  return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionaryObject];
}

-(id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
  // not complete ???
  return (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:value];
}
```

The `?????` is my problem. You see, the method `transformedValue:(id)value` receives value as `id` but I need a `CMTime`. I cannot simply cast it.

Also, when I create an instance of this entity, in theory I should be able to assign the value as this:

```
myEntity.tempo = myCmTimeValue;
```

and I am not seeing how I can do that to an `id`...

also, on `reverseTransformedValue:` I am returning an `id`.

I do not understand that. I want to be able to set and receive a `CMTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMTime` is a struct and `NSValueTransformer` can only be used with objects (pointers).

A workaround is to wrap `CMTime` in `NSValue`

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSValue *tempo;
```

and convert `NSValue` to `CMTime` and vice versa

```
CMTime time = [self.tempo CMTimeValue];


self.tempo = [NSValue valueWithCMTime:time];
```